# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" for flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5

Tags: flutter, dart

my application was working normally with flutter **version1.9.1+hotfix.6** 
when I upgrade flutter to **version1.12.13+hotfix.5** 
the error

> Error generating build_script snapshot: Could not find a file named
>   "pubspec.yaml" in
>   "C:\Users\t.ghassan\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\analyzer-0.35.4".

appears for both the stable channel and the master channel

I didn't use analyzer package in my application

what to do to fix it?

I'm using windows 10

Comment: Looks like an error in Flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42003

Answer (score 0):

`analyzer` is used for all apps to allow `flutter analyze` command from CMD.

What you can do is:

1. Close all IDE or files related to you flutter project
2. Open "C:\Users\t.ghassan\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache" folder
3. Delete "hosted" folder
4. Open your project again and run `flutter packages get`

If this doesn't help let me know in the comments.

Comment: the same error still appears and the hosted folder still missing

Comment: try deleting the 'hosted' directory from `FlutterSDKDir\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted`